# VsCode no escanea caracteres?

Tags: c, vscode

me acabo de instalar VsCode para probarlo pues habia oido hablar muy bien de el , he hecho programas de prueba para ver que tal iba y ahora mismo tengo un problema.
Luego si por ejemplo escribes "Juan" la salida por terminal es solo "J".
¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema? , Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char nombre;

printf("Introduce tu nombre; ");
scanf("%c",&nombre);
printf("tu nombre es %c",nombre);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No tiene relación con VSCode. Es que estás leyendo e imprimiendo un solo caracter, al usar `%c`. Por otro lado tu variable es de tipo `char`. Deberia ser un array de `char` (con espacio suficiente para la respuesta del usuario) y usar `%s` para leerlo y mostrarlo.

Comment: Pero en Clion y CodeBlocks si que se puede hacer eso y te lo escanea como si fuera un string

Comment: ¿Estás seguro? Verifícalo porque creo que estás equivocado. `%c` lee e imprime un solo carácter. Para leer o imprimir un string ha de ser `%s`, y naturalmente la variable en que lo guardes no puede ser `char` sino array o puntero a `char`.

Comment: Si tienes razón , me equivoque.Gracias por responder.